# amd graphics card driver for R5 m330

Tags: drivers, graphics

I recently purchased an Hp laptop that came with 2 Gb  dedicated AMD Radeon R5 Series M330 Graphics .Currently i am running ubuntu 15.04 on my laptop.
I checked for the graphics driver in Hp's website as well as in the AMD's website.I even checked the same in software and updates .But i didn't find any.
How can i download the graphics driver ?

Comment: There is no proprietary drivers for any R5 M300 series. Amd support also said that there is no knowledge if they will suport that series for Linux. Part of the response from them: Response and Service Request History:

We don’t have any update for you in regards to if the Radeon R5 M300 will be supported in future drivers.  I would recommend that you subscribe to AMD and you will be notified when new driver is released.

Answer (score 0):

I found some article where it is said that drivers for M2XX works perfectly even for M3XX. Anyways, having the same card tried

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

and got it working.

Other methods including download of deb packages from *http://amd.com* wasn't working for me, tried packages `fglrx-core` (80MB cca) together with `fglrx` (50MB cca) and had black screen after reboot. I guess there might be some workaround for this method too.